# how to package a reactjs application and make it ready for production to run it without using an IDE?

Tags: reactjs, executable, production

I have created a web application using react js. after finishing the development how to package it in order to run it without using an IDE and make it ready for production? In java we create a jar file and run it.how is it done in react? How to create an executable file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will not be able to create **an executable file** from React app, unless you will use [Electron](https://electronjs.org/)

The thing which you probably think of is bundling the app into single JS and HTML files (or multiple JS files if you are using code splitting).

This can be done by Webpack or other bundlers.

Are you using **create-react-app**? If so, just run `npm run build` inside your project folder. You will get `dist` folder with all JS/HTML/assets which you just have to deploy on your server and that is it.

If you are not using **create-react-app** it would be probably better to use some prepared boilerplate, put your code there and use its `build` script.

Comment: I am using create-react-app

Comment: how to depoly the build folder  on nginx?  @M U

Comment: 1. Use docker
2. Just copy?