# Executing WebStorm-npm project outside WebStorm?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web, npm, webstorm

I have a website project in WebStorm and I'm doing it with React.js and npm. I want to know how to make this project work outside of WebStorm. I mean consider  I have a web server and domain and I want to deploy this project to server and make it public to everyone. What should I do ?

I also want to know is there any way to make this project work outside WebStorm by just clicking `index.html` in my project. I tried this but as you know index.js did not work.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow Yusuf! This question is very broad. You might have a script in `package.json` called e.g. `start` that you can use from the terminal for development that you can use outside Webstorm. How to deploy the application is a whole other topic in of itself.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54591435/how-to-package-a-reactjs-application-and-make-it-ready-for-production-to-run-it